# Javascript: Removing a random string inside a string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to remove the number and braces but splicing results in the string between the index taken from the string. I just want it removed leaving me with: "1234 ..... ABCDEFG"

```
 var mystring = "1234 ..... { 400 } ABCDEFG";

 var s1 = mystring.indexOf("{");
 var s2 = mystring.indexOf("}");        
 mystring = mystring.splice(s1,s2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex replace to just remove the braces and the chars between them:

```
var mystring = "1234 ..... { 400 } ABCDEFG";
mystring = mystring.replace(/\{.*?\}/, "");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sDHc9/

---

If you didn't want to use a regex, you could do it like this:

```
var mystring = "1234 ..... { 400 } ABCDEFG";
var s1 = mystring.indexOf("{");
var s2 = mystring.indexOf("}");   
mystring = mystring.substr(0, s1) + mystring.substr(s2 + 1);
alert(mystring);​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RHhe4/

Answer (score 1):

`splice` is not a `String` method, so your code should throw a `TypeError`

use

```
var mystring = "1234 ..... { 400 } ABCDEFG";
mystring = mystring.replace(/{.+?}/,'');
```

Or, if you really want to use `splice`

```
var mystring = "1234 ..... { 400 } ABCDEFG";
var s1 = mystring.indexOf("{");
var s2 = mystring.indexOf("}");
mystring = [].splice.call(mystring,0,s1)
           .concat([].splice.call(mystring,s2+1))
           .join('');
```